# C++: OpenSSL, aes cfb encryption

Tags: encryption, openssl

I have a simple problem: The first 16 bytes are not encrypted/decrypted correctly.
What is wrong?

The encryption function writes it to a file, and the decryption function reads it from the file again.

```
int inum = 0;

unsigned char ckey [] = "3q43*_;fsdf#ßß94";
unsigned char civ  [] = "sfgsjni274z#-,.-";
```

Encryption:

```
unsigned char outdata [4096 + 1];

AES_KEY key;

AES_set_encrypt_key(ckey, 128, &key); 

AES_cfb128_encrypt((const unsigned char *) "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", outdata, 17, &key, civ, &inum, AES_ENCRYPT);
```

Decryption:

`indata` is set by the read function

```
AES_KEY key;

AES_set_encrypt_key(ckey, 128, &key);

AES_cfb128_encrypt(indata, outdata, iSize, &key, civ, &inum, AES_DECRYPT);
```

The output will be:

```
‡~MÚjô±¦¤,`Ð,-âa
```

Original string is 17 bytes long, so the last byte is correct.

The characters after the the first 16 bytes are always correct, I've tested it with multiple strings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433038/openssl-aes-cfb128-encrypt-c

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I've found this article just a second after i posted the question although i've been searching for hours ...

Comment: Never mind that, your problem should be solved. No harm done :)